# Discrepancy in counts - Oracle SQL group by query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the count of records between 3 PM and 4 PM. The first query returns 473 records whereas the second query returns 474 between 3 PM and 4 PM. Please can you let me know which one could be correct or what I need to do in order to identify the query that provides the accurate result?

```
select count(*) 
from table
where start_ts between 
  to_timestamp('2017-03-06 15:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD     HH24:MI:SS') and to_timestamp('2017-03-06 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')


   select count(*),to_char(start_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') 
from table
where start_ts between 
 to_timestamp('2017-03-06 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD     HH24:MI:SS') and to_timestamp('2017-03-06 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
group by to_char(start_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
order by to_char(start_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
```

Comment: I don't know why you're getting different results, but shouldn't you define the end time as 2017-03-06 15:59:59 to avoid overlapping into the first second of the next hour? I would suggest checking to see if you have a duplicate entry in the table though which is eliminated from the results when you group by.

Comment: nulls.  You have nulls.

Comment: @Hogan . . . `NULL`s would fail the `where` clause in both cases.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around - the first query returns 474 and the second 473? In the second query you are isolating into a separate group the rows with timestamp exactly equal to 4:00:00 pm. In general, such queries should not use BETWEEN; the left inequality should be non-strict (>=) but the right one should be strict (<).

Comment: There are too many other explanations; for example, one more row insertion committed before you running the two queries, or an update committed that changed a timestamp, etc.

Comment: @mathguy : Sorry , the second query that I had pasted was wrong. I modified it now. The first query is returning 473 and second is returning 474.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one guess.  The first query is return 374 records and the second is returning two rows, one with 373 records and one with 1 record.

The 1 record has a time of *exactly* '2017-03-06 16:00:00', so it shows up in a different bin from the rest.

This seems like a plausible explanation, although it requires that the numbers be in the other order.

Comment: Apologies in the second query I have this - to_timestamp('2017-03-06 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD     HH24:MI:SS') and to_timestamp('2017-03-06 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'). I edited my original post as well. I see 1 more value in second query.

Comment: I did further analysis by looking at the count second by second. I see that an entry at 15:00:01 is missing when I do between 15:00:00 to 16:00:00. I do however see all entries starting from 15:00:06.